# Multiple CSS Styles on the same page

Tags: html, css

Picture this scenario:

I have 2 stylesheets. One is a global stylesheet. The other is a page-specific style. They each modify the class `.tobestyled`, but in different ways, i.e., the global says to make the class hidden, while the page-specific says to make it shown.

How can I make the styling in the page-specific stylesheet override the global one?

Comment: Place the page specific stylsheet after the global one in the markup. If that doesn't work, it is an issue of specificity.

Comment: easiest: just be a noob and apply `!important` styles

Comment: @JoshC like so?: `<link href="global.css"><link href="page.css">`?

Comment: http://csscreator.com/node/6989

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the page-specific stylesheet after the global one, that should do it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="global.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="page-specific.css" />
```

If, for some reason, the styles are **not** replaced correctly, add an `!important` clause after the line you want to force, for example:

```
.tobestyled {
    background-color: white !important;
}
```